# Джанго: динамическое генерирование js в отдельном файле

Tags: javascript, django

Возможно ли генерировать с помощью джанго js вне тега script, в ОТДЕЛЬНОМ файле?

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'jquery-3.2.1.min.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#like-button').click(function(){
            url='nutrition/ration_like/ration-{{ ration.id }}/user-{{ profile.user_id }}/';
            $.ajax({
                type : 'GET',
                url : url
            })
        });
    });
```

Как генерить такой же скрипт, только в ОТДЕЛЬНОМ файле, НЕ в HTML шаблоне?

Comment: Просто подключаете как обычный статический файл, да  и всё.

Comment: Статика не обрабатывается шаблонизатором. Не морочьте человеку голову :)

Answer (score 1):

Есть два способа:

#### 1)  Через файл шаблона в templates.

#### 2)  Без файла шаблона в templates.

### 1) С файлом  шаблона:

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'your_script.js$, GenerateScript)
]
```

views.py

```
def GenerateScript(request):

   context = {
    "ration.id": generate_ratio_id,
    "profile.user_id": generate_user_id, 
   }
   return render(requset, "your_script.js", context)
```

templates/your_script.js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'jquery-3.2.1.min.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#like-button').click(function(){
            url='nutrition/ration_like/ration-{{ ration.id }}/user-{{ profile.user_id }}/';
            $.ajax({
                type : 'GET',
                url : url
            })
        });
    });
```

### 2) Без файла в templates можно просто в view написать так:

```
    myscript = '''    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'jquery-3.2.1.min.js' %}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#like-button').click(function(){
                    url='nutrition/ration_like/ration-{{ ration.id }}/user-{{ profile.user_id }}/';
                    $.ajax({
                        type : 'GET',
                        url : url
                    })
                });
            });'''
   myscript = Template(myscript)
   response = render(request, myscript, context)
   return response
```